# Unable to execute dex:Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/marketing/internal/MarketingInitProvider$1;

Tags: android

I have referred android developer web site but could not find solution please help if anyone know solution

Comment: Hi, Mr. Omkar, welcome to stackoverflow.  please edit your question and add the error log and gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is that you have two libraries with the same package name. Could you show build.gradle file?